# Term for a goodbye that takes a long time

Tags: word-requests

Like https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/30115/is-there-an-english-phrase-for-an-inability-to-actually-leave-already , but for Japanese. You're on the driveway, you're saying goodbye ... but you engage in conversation for another half an hour. Is there a term for such a phenomenon in Japanese?

Answer (score 2):

I cannot think of a single word or phrase that every native spekaer would agree on, but you can expect to hear us say:

Noun Phrases:

「帰{かえ}り際{ぎわ}の長話{ながばなし}」, 「帰り際のダラダラ話{ばなし}」, etc.  ("a long chat at the time of departure")

「話」 is pronounced 「**ば**なし」, not 「はなし」 here.

「ダラダラ」 is a perfect onomatopoeia to use for dawdling.

Verb Phrases:

「帰り際に長話（を）する」,「帰り際にダラダラと長話（を）する」, etc.

Comment: I think you may have meant "dawdling", not "doodling".

Answer (score 0):

Though not a "set" phrase, I use the following a lot to describe something like that:

名残{なごり}惜{お}しくて話{はな}し込{こ}む (to talk a while, feeling reluctant to part)

名残惜しい means reluctance/regret to part. Note that this refers to one's feeling, meaning "one feels bad to part with this person/place", so you couldn't use it like "During the protest, the demonstrators were reluctant to leave".

Note that 1) this works either way (for the person staying or for the person leaving) and 2) doesn't really carry the negative connotation as that link you posted.